# unit test a function with router navigateByUrl using karma jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test the following function which has router navigateByUrl , but couldnt execute .then block

**.ts code:**

```
back(){ 

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/routepath').then(() => {

         Object.keys(['column']).forEach((obj, val) => {
            myService.setDefaultGroup();
         });

    });
}
```

Here is what i have tried in my spec.ts

```
class MockRouter {
   navigateByUrl = () => {
    return {
      then: () => {}
     }
   }
}

configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       providers: [{ provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter } ]
    })
});

describe('should call back', () => {
    it('should call Router.navigateByUrl', inject([Router], (router: Router) => {
        const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');
        component.back();
    }));
});
```

What is the output received

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

Expected:

Test case should execute

I am using karma and jasmine to unit test this. Help me out if i am missing anything

Answer (score 0):

When you `spyOn` a method, it stubs it out to return undefined.

You need to use `.and.callThrough()` to not lose implementation details.

Try:

```
describe('should call back', () => {
    it('should call Router.navigateByUrl', inject([Router], (router: Router) => {
        const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl').and.callThrough();
        component.back();
    }));
});
```